Is fetching chat from a youtube stream against ToS?
i'm making an app for youtube content creators and i need to be able to get a stream's live chat in real time
using the official API presents a few big problems, main one being the quota limit being so low and having to poll on intervals instead of being event-driven
now i found these alternatives
https://github.com/LinaTsukusu/youtube-chat
https://github.com/taizan-hokuto/pytchat
these are absolutely perfect for what i need since i only need to fetch the messages, i do not need to interact with them in any way, however this could count as scraping which youtube ToS specifies being not allowed
could someone tell me if using these on a commercial project would cause problems to me or my users? and if so, are there any alternatives to get a livestream messages on real time?
